# Android espresso screenshot with tag

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

is this possible to caputrue screenshot in Espresso and save file with some  information in tag or details section programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific need you should use Spoon (it's a library made by Square quite simple to use).

http://square.github.io/spoon/

```
Spoon.screenshot(activity, "initial_state");
/* Normal test code... */
Spoon.screenshot(activity, "after_login");
```